# Find the dimension of the vector subspace W

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $M_n(R)$ be the real vector space of all $n \times n$ matrices with real entries $n\geq2$. Let $A \in M_n(R)$. Consider the subspace $W$ of $M_n(R)$ spanned by $\{1, A, A^2, ...\}$. Find the dimension of $W$ over $V$ .

My approach:

Since $W$ is spanned by $\{1, A, A^2, ...\}$, we can write $W = \{aI + bA + cA^2 + ... |\space a, b, c \in R\}$

This is similar to the set of all polynomials of degree at most $n$ whose dimension is $n + 1$. So the dimension of $W$ is also $n + 1$ i.e., at least $n\space$.

Is this answer correct?

Comment: Do you know about the minimal polynomial?

Comment: You will have to find how many of those $1, A, A^2, \ldots$ are linearly independent, right? For example if $A = 1$ then the vector space would just be dimension $1$. And to see how many of those are linearly independent, minimal polynomial should help as told by the other comment.